# Fetching url query parameters inside php case

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have below index.php file which will handle all routes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <?php
    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($request){
    case '/': require __DIR__.'/index1.php';break;
    case '/home':require __DIR__.'/views/home.php';break;
    default: echo("wrong");}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And below file is home.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$str=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo($str);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In case of no query strings, the above setup works fine. But how will I include the condition in which user hits `127.0.0.1/home?1234`. In this case, any case statement will become invalid and it will return wrong. How would I change this so that it goes to appropriate route along with query string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use regex or string functions. Use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url) to extract the path (or just about any portion) from a URL:

```php
$path = parse_url("/home?1234", PHP_URL_PATH);
# $path will be "/home"
switch ($path) {
   ...
```

Comment: And how will I fetch the query string, 1234?

Comment: Pass `PHP_URL_QUERY` or `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
$str = $uri[0]
```